# Allocation Memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have a memory allocation problem in my application. This is causing the freezing and finally the end of my program. Reviewing my code, I realized most of allocation of memory is in the CFString. Below is the class that is causing this problem.

```
#import "iMAPProdutosPesquisar.h"
#import "iMAPArrayProdutos.h"
#import "iMAPTabela.h"
#import "iMAPProdutosFiltro.h"
#import "iMAPArrayAbreviatura.h"

static NSString *dadosProdutos = nil;

@implementation iMAPProdutosPesquisar

@synthesize pop;
@synthesize tv;
@synthesize sb;
@synthesize datBaseName;
@synthesize datBasePath;
@synthesize iMAP;
@synthesize abrev;
@synthesize opcFil;
@synthesize cab;
@synthesize cons;

#define TAG_1 1 
#define TAG_2 2
#define TAG_3 3

#define FIRST_CELL_IDENTIFIER @"TrailItemCell" 
#define SECOND_CELL_IDENTIFIER @"RegularCell"

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [pop release];
    [tv release];
    [sb release];
    [datBaseName release];
    [datBasePath release];
    [iMAP release];
    [abrev release];
    [opcFil release];
    [cab release];
    [cons release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self initDatBase];

    [cab setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cabecalho-produtos.png"]];
    cab.opaque = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [self setPop:nil];
    [self setTv:nil];
    [self setSb:nil];
    [self setDatBaseName:nil];
    [self setDatBasePath:nil];
    [self setIMAP:nil];
    [self setAbrev:nil];
    [self setOpcFil:nil];
    [self setCab:nil];
    [self setCons:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    [self initDatBase];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark tableView delegates

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {

    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    return [iMAP count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

    iMAPArrayProdutos *arrayProd = (iMAPArrayProdutos *)[iMAP objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *myIdent = @"myIdent";

    iMAPTabela *tab = (iMAPTabela *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdent];

    tv.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    if (tab == nil) {

        tab = [[[iMAPTabela alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:myIdent] autorelease];

        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0, 150.0, tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];

        [tab addColumn:170];

        label.tag = TAG_1; 
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]; 
        label.text = arrayProd.cod;
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 

        [tab.contentView addSubview:label]; 

        label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180.0, 0, 150.0, tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease]; 

        [tab addColumn:340];

        label.tag = TAG_2; 
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]; 
        label.text = arrayProd.artrf2;
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 

        [tab.contentView addSubview:label];

        label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350.0, 0, 418.0, tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease]; 

        [tab addColumn:768];

        label.tag = TAG_3; 
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]; 
        label.text = arrayProd.descri;    
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 

        [tab.contentView addSubview:label];
    }

    UILabel *label_1 = (UILabel *)[tab.contentView viewWithTag:TAG_1];
    label_1.text = arrayProd.cod;

    UILabel *label_2 = (UILabel *)[tab.contentView viewWithTag:TAG_2];
    label_2.text = arrayProd.artrf2;

    UILabel *label_3 = (UILabel *)[tab.contentView viewWithTag:TAG_3];
    label_3.text = arrayProd.descri;

    return tab;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    iMAPArrayProdutos *arrayProd = (iMAPArrayProdutos *)[iMAP objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [iMAPProdutosPesquisar setDefaultValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", arrayProd.cod]];
}

- (IBAction)fil:(id)sender {

    iMAPProdutosFiltro *prodFil = [[iMAPProdutosFiltro alloc] init];
    pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:prodFil];

    prodFil.pop = pop;

    [prodFil release];

    [pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(170, 220)];
    [pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

- (void)initDatBase {

    datBaseName = @"iMAP.sqlite";

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    datBasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:datBaseName];

    [self checkAndCreateDatBase];
    [self readFilFromDatBase];

    if ([sb.text length] > 0) {

        [self readAvancFromDatBase];
    }

    [self readProdFromDatBase];
}

- (void)checkAndCreateDatBase {

    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:datBasePath];

    if(success) {

        return;
    }

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:datBaseName];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:datBasePath error:nil];

    [fileManager release];
}

- (void)readFilFromDatBase {

    sqlite3 *datBase;

    if(sqlite3_open([datBasePath UTF8String], &datBase) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sqlStat = "SELECT OPCAO FROM FILTRO WHERE R_E_C_N_O_ = 2";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStat;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(datBase, sqlStat, -1, &compiledStat, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStat) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                opcFil = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStat, 0)];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStat);
    }

    sqlite3_close(datBase);
}

- (void)readAvancFromDatBase {

    sqlite3 *datBase;

    abrev = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(sqlite3_open([datBasePath UTF8String], &datBase) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sqlStat;
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStat;

        NSString *string1;
        NSString *string2;

        string1 = @"SELECT ABV_COMPLETA FROM ABREV WHERE ABV_REDUZ LIKE '%";
        string2 = @"%'";

        NSString *result =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", string1, sb.text, string2]; 

        sqlStat = [result UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(datBase, sqlStat, -1, &compiledStat, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStat) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSString *abvCompl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStat, 0)];

                iMAPArrayAbreviatura *arrayAbrev = [[iMAPArrayAbreviatura alloc] reduz:nil completa:abvCompl observacao:nil abrUnq:nil recno:nil];

                [abrev addObject:arrayAbrev];

                [arrayAbrev release];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStat);
    }

    sqlite3_close(datBase);
}

- (void)readProdFromDatBase {

    sqlite3 *datBase;

    iMAP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(sqlite3_open([datBasePath UTF8String], &datBase) == SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStat;
        const char *sqlStat;

        if ([sb.text length] == 0) {

            sqlStat = "SELECT COD, ARTRF2, DESCRI FROM APSB1010";
        }
        else {

            NSString *string1;
            NSString *string2 = @"%'";
            NSString *result;

            if ([opcFil isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

                string1 = @"SELECT COD, ARTRF2, DESCRI FROM APSB1010 WHERE TRIM(COD) LIKE '%";

                result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", string1, sb.text, string2]; 
            }
            else if ([opcFil isEqualToString:@"2"]) {

                string1 = @"SELECT COD, ARTRF2, DESCRI FROM APSB1010 WHERE TRIM(ARTRF2) LIKE '%";

                result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", string1, sb.text, string2];
            }
            else if ([opcFil isEqualToString:@"3"]) {

                string1 = @"SELECT COD, ARTRF2, DESCRI FROM APSB1010 WHERE TRIM(DESCRI) LIKE '%";

                result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", string1, sb.text, string2];
            }
            else if ([opcFil isEqualToString:@"4"]) {

                string1 = @"SELECT COD, ARTRF2, DESCRI FROM APSB1010 WHERE TRIM(APLICA) LIKE '%";

                result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", string1, sb.text, string2];
            }
            else {

                string1 = @"SELECT COD, ARTRF2, DESCRI FROM APSB1010 WHERE (";
                NSString *string1 = @"SELECT * FROM APSB1010 WHERE (";
                NSString *string3 = @"TRIM(DESCRI) LIKE '%";
                NSString *string4 = @" OR ";
                NSString *string5 = @")";
                cons = [[NSString alloc] init];

                for (int i = 0; i < [abrev count]; i++) {

                    iMAPArrayAbreviatura *arrayAbrev = (iMAPArrayAbreviatura *)[abrev objectAtIndex:i];

                    if (i > 0) {

                        cons = [cons stringByAppendingString:string4];
                    }

                    cons = [cons stringByAppendingString:string3];
                    cons = [cons stringByAppendingString:arrayAbrev.completa];
                    cons = [cons stringByAppendingString:string2];
                }

                result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", string1, cons, string5];
            }

            sqlStat = [result UTF8String];
        }

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(datBase, sqlStat, -1, &compiledStat, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStat) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSString *prodCod = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStat, 0)];
                NSString *prodDescri = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStat, 2)];
                NSString *prodArtrf2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStat, 1)];

                iMAPArrayProdutos *arrayProd = [[iMAPArrayProdutos alloc] cod:prodCod prv1:nil grupo:nil picment:nil descri:prodDescri artrf2:prodArtrf2 um:nil embAp:nil desMax:nil imgAp:nil aplica:nil qAtu_01:nil qAtu_11:nil qAtu_12:nil qAtu_13:nil qAtu_14:nil prProm:nil recno:nil];

                [iMAP addObject: arrayProd];

                [arrayProd release];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStat);
    }

    sqlite3_close(datBase);

    [tv reloadData];
}

+ (NSString*)defaultValue {

    return dadosProdutos;
}

+ (void)setDefaultValue:(NSString*)newDefaultValue {

    if(dadosProdutos != newDefaultValue) {

        [dadosProdutos release];

        dadosProdutos = [newDefaultValue retain];
    }
}

@end
```

Someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'm getting crazy with this problem.

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete and concise–enough to recreate the issue but no more. The posted sample has too much extraneous code.

Comment: I hope someone around will slog to find and solve the bug here. However, it will be nice if you can add as much more info as you can to simply their task. You could highlight the code where you suspect the bug could be, to start with, I suppose.

Comment: To find memory leaks, you should use [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). In addition to Apple's guide, a web search will turn up many, many tutorials on the topic.

Comment: If you want a code review, ask on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However, in this case the best course would be as outlined above (reduce the sample code, ask a more directed question, read up on Instruments).

Answer (score 2):

You've got a bunch of places where you do stuff like

```
datBaseName = @"iMAP.sqlite";
```

I assume that `datBaseName` is defined as a retained property, but this here just sets the instance variable without calling the accessor, so when you call

```
[datBaseName release]
```

You're trying to release a constant string - bad things will happen. Instead you should do

```
self.datBaseName = @"iMAP.sqlite";
```

You're also doing stuff like this

```
datBasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:datBaseName];
```

again this isn't calling the accessor, so `datBasePath` isn't being retained and will probably have been released by the time you try and use it.

There may well be other issues - try and reduce the problem to a more minimal example where the problems will be easier to spot. Also look into [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html) which takes some of the drudgery out of memory management. Xcode also has a bunch of tools such as `NSZombies` for tracking down issues like this.